max size for wxSplitterWindow
Is it possible to set max size for panel inside a wxSplitterWindow? I need to split window verticaly in two sides: the left side has to have min(it is possible with SetMinimumPaneSize) and max size, the right side should be flexible as it is in example.
I found this example, but cant find a way to prevent left panel resize more than X in width:
    this->SetSize(wxSize(350, 350));
    Centre();

    wxSplitterWindow* splitter = new wxSplitterWindow(this, wxID_ANY, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize,
        wxSP_BORDER | wxSP_LIVE_UPDATE);

    wxSplitterWindow* right_splitter = new wxSplitterWindow(splitter, wxID_ANY, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize,
        wxSP_BORDER | wxSP_LIVE_UPDATE);
    
    
    wxPanel* left = new wxPanel(splitter);
    left->SetBackgroundColour(*wxBLUE);
    left->SetMaxSize(wxSize(400, -1));
    //splitters
    wxPanel* right = new wxPanel(right_splitter);
    wxPanel* bottom = new wxPanel(right_splitter);

    //left->SetBackgroundColour(wxColor(200, 100, 100));
    right->SetBackgroundColour(wxColor(100, 200, 100));
    bottom->SetBackgroundColour(wxColor(200, 200, 100));

    right_splitter->SetMinimumPaneSize(100);
    right_splitter->SplitHorizontally(right, bottom);

    right_splitter->SetSashGravity(0);

    splitter->SetMinimumPaneSize(200);

    splitter->SplitVertically(left, right_splitter);

If it is not possible, how can i do it in other way?

I don't think its possible. The right panel will occupy all leftover space.

There is no built-in way to do it, but you can override OnSashPositionChanging() to return -1 if the new sash position is outside of the allowed range.
